# How to install plug-in in Gimp on OS X?

Tags: image-editing

I've got the Gimp for Mac OS X installed and working in my installation of Mac OS X 10.6.4. A very important tool I need is the David's Batch Processor plugin ( http://members.ozemail.com.au/~hodsond/dbp.html ) for batch auto-adjusting contrast/brightness/colour for my images.

There are no Mac specific instructions provided on the software's website saying how to install the python-based plugin. Can anyone please teach me how to install plugins for Gimp in Mac OS X?

Comment: What *bundle* of Gimp for Mac OS X did you choose (where do you get Gimp from) ?

Comment: I got it from here: http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/News/News.html Any hope?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've managed to get DBP installed on my Mac (version 10.6.8). I've made the compiled plugin available on my blog, since compiling Gimp from MacPorts took an overnight compilation session, and is way too much hassle for folks who just want to plug-n-play.

So... anyone is welcome to [grab my binary](http://blog.jondh.me.uk/2011/07/davids-batch-processor-on-os-x/) as they wish. If it's useful, please comment, and if it doesn't work, please comment; in either case if you can state versions of OS X and Gimp, that will hopefully help other users trying to avoid compiling it themselves!

Comment: I got the plugin to work once. But now GIMP tells me the plugin crashed everytime I try to start it. I am running GIMP 2.6.11 on Mac OS X 10.6.8.
I tried to reinstall GIMP 2.6.11 via Macports and from http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/News/News.html, but now the plugin is not even showing up. (I did make sure the plugin is in the right folder). Please advise! Thanks.

Comment: Ah, as per my latest comments on my blog post - I think the binary I've compiled has dependencies that are only satisfied by installing Gimp via macports anyway (i.e. presently you may as well compile yourself). I uninstalled my macports Gimp, and the plugin stopped working in the binary version - it was fine before. I will reinstall Gimp via macports and see if I can compile the plugin with all dependencies included; if I am successful I will post on my blog.

Comment: halfer: saw your blog post, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: All: I've added a new solution to my blog post. Essentially I've copied the gimp libraries from the MacPorts version and made them available as a zipfile, and DBP now seems to start fine, even when the MP version is uninstalled or deactivated. Yay!

Comment: @penyuan, you're welcome. Let me know on my post if it works for you, so other people know whether it is worth trying :)

Answer (score 11):

You'll find the appropriate folders at `/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Gimp/`. There go in the scripts folder
and the presets go in the gimpressionist folder

I found these locations by looking at the GIMP preferences, and clicking on Scripts. The locations cited above were listed there.

Comment: Slight change in the naming convention in recent years.  `/Users/username/Library/Application Support/GIMP/version/.`

Answer (score 5):

There are OS X instructions in the [GIMP documentation](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-scripting.html#gimp-plugins-install) and they suggest installing GIMP from fink or macports. Do this and you can follow the Linux/Unix instructions for plugin installation. Otherwise, the documentation states "good luck" if you install it some other way.

However, searching http://gimper.net suggests that, for a Python plugin, you should put it in: `[your home]/Library/Applications Support/Gimp/plug-ins` (create directory if necessary).